# Can sitemap.xml be misused to copy entire website?

Tags: web, copy, sitemap

I am planning to upload sitemap.xml on my website having generated content pages. As of now, if I try to copy the entire website using tools like HTTrack etc., it cannot be copied.

Now if I want search bots to find and index content pages on this website, I will have to include all urls in the sitemap.xml file.

So the question is - will such a sitemap.xml expose all urls thereby "facilitating" full copy of the website ?

Inputs on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, yes.

But I suppose the question you really need to ask is 'Do I care'
If the answer is yes, you should really consider if you should be publishing it to the web in the first place?

A well constructed [IA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_architecture) would contain links between each pages anyway (for navigational and SEO reasons), so tools like HTTrack would be able to copy the site anyway.

Anything you don't want to be seen by HTTrack needs also to be invisible to the ordinary web user - ie either password protected, or non-existent.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I am afraid, my fears have come true.

The content pages are not hidden from users or even HTTrack. However, when I tried using HTTrack to copy the entire website, it could not copy it. So something did prevent it from copying the whole website content.

My concern was whether sitemap.xml would enable HTTrack to copy the entire site, which I think it will.

So I will have to opt out of using sitemap.xml.

Comment: On second thought, is there any way to grant access to sitemap.xml only to specific crawlers - like the well known crawlers from google, yahoo, bing etc. ?

Comment: If HTTrack can't 'copy' your website, then crawlers etc... can't properly spider your content, and you will have problems with pagerank.

Comment: In answer to you second question, no. Crawlers are just like web users, accessing your site over port 80. You really need to evaluate what is important. People being able to see freely your content, or keeping it private. You can't have both